# SQL query min and max group by flag

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as below :

[image: Table]

How can I craft a SQL `select` statement so that `MIN AND MAX EVENT DATE` groups results by `FLAG (0,1)`?

So the result would be:

[image: Result]

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: using ms sql server

Comment: Should it be grouping by desc_reader (the location)? The schema seems to allow entry and exit to be via different readers but your example results imply they are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative if Window function does not work:

```
 SELECT 
       t1.card_no, t1.descr_reader,
       t1.event_date date_in,
       (select top 1 event_date from test t2
        where t2.card_no = t1.card_no and
              t2.reader_no = t1.reader_no and
              t2.descr_reader = t1.descr_reader and
              t2.event_date > t1.event_date and
              t2.flag = 1
        order by t2.event_date ) as date_out
FROM test t1 
WHERE t1.flag = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do conditional aggregation with use of *window function*

```
SELECT card_no, descr_reader,
       max(CASE WHEN flag = 0 THEN event_date END) date_in,
       max(CASE WHEN flag = 1 THEN event_date END) date_out 
FROM
(
     SELECT *,
               COUNT(flag) OVER (PARTITION BY flag ORDER BY id) Seq
     FROM table t
)t
GROUP BY card_no, descr_reader, Seq
```

Comment: its not working, error code: "[Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'order'.

Comment: sql syntax : SELECT card_no, desc_reader,
       max(CASE WHEN flag = 0 THEN event_date END) date_in,
       max(CASE WHEN flag = 1 THEN event_date END) date_out 
FROM
(
     SELECT *,
               COUNT(flag) OVER (PARTITION BY flag ORDER BY id) Seq
     FROM TES
)t
GROUP BY card_no, desc_reader, Seq

Comment: @troey.. which version ??